# Remove all whitespaces between two characters regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord, discord.js

I have a translation bot which recently I have modified to allow custom emojis ( the translator would add in whitespaces everywhere and translate the emoji name to an unsupported format )

My issue right now is it does not always function as needed,   and I want to add in a 'filter' to remove any white spaces for al custom emojis and emojis to remove any whitespaces that may have been left out in my regex statement if it was not triggered.

Currently the code works as follows:

[The Regex Editor Can Be Found Here](https://regex101.com/r/07mRib/3)

```js
const regex = /<([:+\s:\s*[a-z0-9ЁёА-я_\s]+:\s*)([0-9\s]+)>/gmi;
const str = "<: Gelb: 590653333124022288><:Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: gelb : 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Rot  : 538473333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>"
const subst = `<:okthisisanemoji:$2>`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, subst));
```

(edit, the reason I have it changing all emoji names to :okthisisanemoji: is so that I do not have to deal with translated emoji names which discord cannot send as,  for example discord cannot send emojis with russian letters)

Can someone help me modify/create a new regex statement,
which removes all white spaces between the characters "<" and ">"?

Apologies if the above explanation is mis-leading, let me clarify.    To remove all whitespaces between "<" and ">" but leave the rest of the string alone otherwise,  and to remove "<" and ">" globally.

I have attempted to look online for help, on discord too but nothing for javascript or a regex statement that would do this.    I have tried doing it in regex but have epicly failed as I do not use regex much.

Source code right now is here:    https://github.com/Zyc0r3/RitaBot/tree/test-branch      src/core/send.js has the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist on your problem's being solved by only one regular expression, below is a solution using two: first to select tags between `<:` and `>`, second to replace all spaces in the second in a callback function.

```js
const input = `<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<:Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: gelb : 590653333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> 
<: Rot  : 538473333124022288> 
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>"`;

console.log(input.replace(/<:.+?>/g, tag => tag.replace(/\s+/g, '')));
```

Comment: Thank you!    It serves as a "fact checker" of sorts,   because this will run every time a message with <: exists while the code I posted above doesnt run every time due to the way it is set up to do so.   Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single lookaround-based regex pass:

```js
string.replace(/(?<=<:[^<>]*?)\s+(?=[^<>]*>)/g, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqnS20/1). Details:

- `(?<=<:[^<>]*?)` - a location in string that is immediately preceded with `<:` and then any amount of chars other than `<` and `>`, as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[^<>]*>)` - a location in string that is immediately followed with any amount of chars other than `<` and `>`, as many as possible, and then `>`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /(?<=<:[^<>]*?)\s+(?=[^<>]*>)/g;
const str = "<: Gelb: 590653333124022288><:Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: gelb : 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Rot  : 538473333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>"
console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```